# Using AssetBundle in Unity INCREASES Memory Allocation

Tags: api, memory, unity-game-engine, memory-management, bundle

i have a login scene which goes to a dashboard scene then to one of many gametype scenes. I decided to asset bundle the different scenes to make it so that i don't have to allocate every image and prefab all the time. The problem is, using asset bundling made my game less efficient. I ran the profiler with and without bundle asset capability. So both tests go from login scene -> dashboard scene, can anyone explain this?

WITH BUNDLE ASSETS login scene total memory allocated: 0.78GB after transition to dashboard scene total memory allocated: 0.99GB

WITHOUT BUNDLE ASSETS login scene total memory allocated: 0.76GB after transition to dashboard scene total memory allocated: 0.82GB

I also tested on WebGL both versions, and once i got to the dashboard on each version, there was a 10% decrease in fps in the bundle asset version. So the version with bundle assets had a lower frame rate and higher memory allocation. Just the opposite of what i was trying to do, any ideas of what could be going on?

And for the record i removed the scenes I'm loading from the build settings when testing the bundle asset versions

Thanks Mitch

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you [AssetBundle Compression Overhead](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundleCompression.html)

Also, are you unloading the AssetBundles once you have instantiated the objects with [Unload(false)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.Unload.html). If not, I think you will have in memory both the asset and the bundle.